# Should DynamoDB be the default recommendation for AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Now that DynamoDB supports transactions for up to ten items, and also offers API for consistent reads, shouldn't it be the default selection for database on AWS? Not only is it providing all features of RDBMS, but much more because it is fully managed by AWS, provides fantastic features like DAX (inbuilt cache) and streams, and tuned for single digit latency.

Comment: phrases `providing all features of RDBMS` and `tuned for single digit latency` are not actually true, also don't forget about cost

Comment: Database design is not the same  between RDBMS and DynamoDB. Wrong selection of keys can result in high cost in DynamoDB and there is very little opportunity to correct it. You can have multiple indexes on RDBMS tables and can be added once the table us created. There are many other things which makes them different. So DynamoDB does not simply replace the RDBMS.

Answer (score 4):

DynamoDB does not provide all of the features of a RDBMS. Notable things lacking are are multi-table joins, efficient querying by non-indexed attributes, aggregation queries, and supporting adhoc access patterns.

Regarding latency, single digit millisecond latency is the fastest you are likely to achieve.

As in most software development and infrastructure design choices, the correct implementation depends on the requirements. There is no one size fits all approach.